# Why oracle spool inserting new line character before every column?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, spool

My .sql file is spooling records, I am encountered '\n' before and after every column in my output

```
set serveroutput off;
set feedback off;
set linesize 10000;
set pagesize 1000;
set trimspool on;
set underline off;

spool test.txt
select buname||'|',listagg(email,',') within group (order by buname) from test;
spool off;
```

Output File looks like

```
BU_NAME

EMAIL_D

TES Goaplianqe|
HONIKA.GTAGAY@XXYYYZZZ.COM
```

Octal Dump of output file is as below

```
    0000000  \n   B   U   _   N   A   M   E   ,   E   M   A   I   L   _   I
    0000020   D  \n  \n   T   E   S       G   o   a   p   l   a   a   n   q
    0000040   e   |  \n   H   O   U   I   K   A   .   G   T   A   G   A   Y
    0000060   @   X   X   Y   Y   Y   Z   Z   Z   .   C   O   M  \n  \n
```

It shows '\n' character is surrounded at start and end to each column.

P.S. above code works well on oracle 11g, but issue is in 12c. Please help

Comment: The query you showed isn't going to produce the output you've shown (and is missing a group-by, so it will only work with a single row), and the text output doesn't match the `od -c` output. Which makes it hard to guess what's really going on. Can you create a complete, reproducible and consistent example, and also say exactly which Oracle versions you're using, and which clients?

Comment: Yes, i know. It's confidential data so I just can copy paste it, hence I morphed it. Basically it contains \n character at start and end of columns. Using 12.1 DB version and connecting through 11g version of SQL plus client

Comment: Substituting fake data is fine of course, but you have to do it consistently. There are too many discrepancies to guess what might really be wrong in your actual code. I'd suggest you use a CTE to provide made-up data for the query, and then show the actual query and results for that. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).